# HP Proliant DL380 gen9 SATA drives

Tags: hp-proliant, sata

Considering buying this server. It has 16GB RAM, two 300GB SAS drives, and two Xeon E5-2640v4 processors.  It appears that the backplane is capable of either SAS or SATA drives and I was hoping someone would confirm that for me. I have checked HP support for this model and it seems to say that is the case. However what I am not sure of is whether the backplane in the unit had this capability or whether a different backplane is required. Clearly I am new to this! I have seen that Lenovo servers have this capability but wasn’t 100% sure that this is the case for HP servers also.

Comment: AFAIK Pretty universally SATA drives will fit and work in a SAS slot, so you can usually mix SAS and SATA drives when your backplane supports SAS. The inverse is not true, you can't fit SAS drives in a SATA only backplane. - You can't group and mix SAS/ SATA/SSD in a single logical volume, they must all be off the same type https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=emr_na-c03424975  but you should be able to create two or more logical volumes/arrays, one for the SAS drives and another for your SATA drives. See page 8 https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=c03909334

Comment: Not all SAS controllers support SATA drives though. Additionally, there may have vendor restrictions on the controller as to what drive models you can use.

Comment: Thanks guys, appreciate the advice

Answer (score 1):

I can say yes, the HPE ProLiant DL380 Gen9 server is compatible with both SAS and SATA drives. The server supports up to twelve 3.5-inch or twenty-four 2.5-inch hot-plug drive bays, and the drive backplane is flexible enough to accommodate both SAS and SATA drives.

If the server you're looking at has a 3.5-inch drive bay, you can use either 3.5-inch SAS or SATA drives. If it has a 2.5-inch drive bay, you can use either 2.5-inch SAS or SATA drives.

You can verify the specific configuration of the server you are looking at with the seller or by checking the server's product documentation. The product documentation should specify whether the server comes with a SAS or SATA backplane, or if it is configurable for both.

In general, SAS drives are typically more expensive than SATA drives but offer better performance, higher reliability, and support for larger capacities. SATA drives, on the other hand, are generally cheaper but offer lower performance and lower reliability than SAS drives. Your choice of drive will depend on your specific requirements for performance, reliability, and cost.You may find [this page](https://hpe.to/6603OJgy9) be more helpful.